# How to downloads video file with https using ffmpeg

Tags: android-ffmpeg

How to using FFmpeg download a video file with https.

I have using FFmpeg on Android to download a video file with https. But can't download. because of FFmpeg doesn't support https.

```
ffmpeg -i https://example.com/video.mp4 -c copy b.mp4
```

Logs

```
    ffmpeg version 3.2.9 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers  configuration: 
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
https protocol not found, recompile FFmpeg with openssl, gnutls or securetransport enabled.
```

Comment: The solution is right there in what you have quoted. If you are not on a system where you can do that, then you will need to use something else to download the video first (f.e. wget or curl), and then pass the local file to ffmpeg in a second step afterwards.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have recompile but occurred some errors. I will try it again.